# gh workflow run not working for particular branch

Tags: github-actions, github-cli

I've two branch in my repo i.e `main` and `kaju1`,

On `main` branch *(default)*, there are two workflow defined `push.yml` and `test.yml`.

On `kaju1` branch, there are three workflow defined `push.yml`, `test.yml`, and `pr.yml`.

I want to trigger `pr.yml` i.e on `kaju1` branch using github cli.

I tried using this code:

```yaml
gh workflow run --repo username/repo-name --ref kaju1 pr.yml
```

But this is returning me the following error:

```
HTTP 404: Not Found (https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo-name/actions/workflows/pr.yml)
```

Comment: The third workflow (`pr.yml`) should also be present in the default branch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did some research and found out that workflow only work with two conditions

1. It is present in `main` *(default)* branch.
2. It is present in some other branch but has already run before.

So what I came up with, I'll keep it in other branch (that I want), then I'll add `on:push` trigger on it for that it get triggered on every push to that branch then I'll use `if/else` to distinguish between `on:push` and `on:workflow_dispach`

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "other-branch"

  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      greeting:
        description: 'Greetings'
        required: true
        default: 'Hello, World'
        type: string

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

now on every push It'll at least get registered in `github/actionss`, then

```
 gh workflow run --repo username/repo-name --ref other-branch pr.yml
```